# bubble sort not sorting properly

Tags: c++, sorting, for-loop, nested-loops, bubble-sort

Im trying to sort this random generated array,  but my output isincorrect it looks like this:

```
sorted round: 0: 87
sorted round: 0: 78
sorted round: 0: 16
sorted round: 0: 94
sorted round: 0: 36
sorted round: 0: 93
sorted round: 0: 50
sorted round: 0: 22
sorted round: 0: 63
sorted round: 0: 28
sorted round: 0: 91
sorted round: 0: 60
sorted round: 0: 64
sorted round: 0: 27
sorted round: 0: 41
sorted round: 0: 73
sorted round: 0: 37
sorted round: 0: 12
sorted round: 0: 69
84
78
16
87
36
93
50
22
63
28
91
60
64
27
41
73
37
12
69 0
```

ive been at this for hours and havnt been able to  figure out what im doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // for std::find
#include <iterator> // for std::begin, std::end
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int random_array[20];
    int i;
    int j;
    random_array[0]=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;

    for (i=1; i<20;)
    {
        j= rand()%(100-1+1)+1;
        bool exists;
        exists = find(begin(random_array), end(random_array), j) != end(random_array);
        if(!exists)
        {
            random_array[i]=j;
            i=i+1;
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    int size=20;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    int k =0;
    
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
        for (j; j < size - i; j++) 
        {
            for(k; k<20; k++)
            {
                cout<<"sorted round: "<<j<<": "<<random_array[k]<<endl;
            }
            if (random_array[j] > random_array[j + 1]) {
                swap(random_array[j], random_array[j + 1]);
                
            }
            else
            {
                ;
            }
            
           
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<20;i++)
    {
        cout<<random_array[i]<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The out put should be a sorted array called random_array and the issue im running into starts on this line of code:

```
int size=20;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    int k =0;
    
    for (i; i < size; i++) {
```

Comment: What *should* your output be?  What is the *first* line of your code that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: Is this an assignment? If not use std::sort (its also in algorithm and it is a good thing to learn to reuse tested code), otherwise split up your algorithm into smaller functions like, initialize_values, swap (or use std::swap) so your code reads a bit more like what it's doing instead of how its doing it.  Replace 20 with a constant value. And also check your inner loops are they starting at the indices where they should? And most importantly, use a debugger and single step through your code. Where does it start to behave differently then expected?

Comment: This is an assignment where bubble sort is expected

Comment: `random_array`s elements are not initialized and you invoke undefined behavior when calling `find` to scan all elements till `end(random_array)` you can only use the elements that already have been initialized

Comment: an `if` does not necessarily need an `else`. You can remove `else { ; }`

Comment: Note: You seem to have forgotten to seed the random number generator. You'll want to use a fixed seed when testing so you can get reproducible results, but later when you want those random numbers to be changing on each run, you'll want to vary the seed in some hard-to-predict way.

Comment: Use `std::shuffle` to generate a random permutation of the numbers 1-20 as your test case. Picking 20 unique numbers between 1-100 makes no difference to testing your code and is just inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these nested for loops

```
for (i; i < size; i++) {
    for (j; j < size - i; j++) 
    {
        for(k; k<20; k++)
        {
            cout<<"sorted round: "<<j<<": "<<random_array[k]<<endl;
        }
        if (random_array[j] > random_array[j + 1]) {
            swap(random_array[j], random_array[j + 1]);
            
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
        
       
    }
}
```

neither variable `j` nor the variable `k` are reset to 0 in each iteration of the most outer loop

```
for (i; i < size; i++) {
```

At least you should write

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < size - i; j++) 
    {
        for(k = 0; k<20; k++)
        {
            cout<<"sorted round: "<<j<<": "<<random_array[k]<<endl;
        }
        if (random_array[j] > random_array[j + 1]) {
            swap(random_array[j], random_array[j + 1]);
            
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
        
       
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that the program invokes undefined behavior in the first iteration of the most outer loop that is when `i` is equal to `0` because in this if statement

```
        if (random_array[j] > random_array[j + 1]) {
```

the expression `random_array[j + 1]` accesses memory beyond the array when j is equal `size - 1`.

It is better to start the inner for loop with 1

```
    for (j = 1; j < size - i; j++) 
    {
```

and in if statement to write

```
        if (random_array[j-1] > random_array[j]) {
```

Comment: for OP: the `i;` in `for (i; i < size; i++) {` does nothing. Its the same as writing `for ( ; i < size; i++) {`